# Make windows 10 recognize a application as a communication program for audio device

Tags: windows-10, audio, music, audio-output, voice-chat

### Question

I have set one output device (my speakers) as my ***default audio output*** and another output device (my headphones) as ***my default communications device***. I have several programs that I use for communication (most often a casual game, web browser or other program that uses voicechat), that windows does not put on my default communication device.

*Is there a way that I can tell windows that a program is a communications program?* Then I can keep talking to people on my headset while playing music (or video, or any other non-chat audio) on my speakers.

### Practical example

Say a headset is connected to the ASUS MG279 and speakers to the TX-NR626:

[image: output devices]

And for example Spotify is playing music and I`m using voicechat on Chrome:

[image: running applications]

Then Windows just plays everything on my speakers:

[image: even my voice chat is on default audio]

An nothing on my communication device:

[image: communication device not used for my voice chat]

How do I tell Windows that Chrome is a communication app?

### Related questions

My question is about functionality thats built into windows (seperate output for communication and non-cummunication audio). If that does not work a generic solution to split up programs to audio devices would be just as good, but the following questions show that that is not possible in (any version of) Windows:

- [How can I switch an application to a different playback device on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/968828/how-can-i-switch-an-application-to-a-different-playback-device-on-windows-10)
- [Routing Applications sound to different sound device? (Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/258969/routing-applications-sound-to-different-sound-device-windows)
- [How do I use different audio devices for different apps in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/500117/how-do-i-use-different-audio-devices-for-different-apps-in-windows-8?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Routing sound in Windows 7 to separate devices](https://superuser.com/questions/554993/routing-sound-in-windows-7-to-separate-devices?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: It’s not Windows that decides were applications direct their audio to. It’s the applications themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This app ([article](https://www.theverge.com/2018/6/13/17457778/eartrumpet-windows-10-audio-app)) turned up in my google assistant feed on my mobile. Its called Eartrumpet ([this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtLvn.gif)) and it lets you assign any app to any output. I have only been able to download it through the [microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/eartrumpet/9nblggh516xp), but its free. ([source code](https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet/releases))